# Novel about a man who seeks revenge against villains for attacking his planet

Tags: story-identification, books, space, space-opera

I remember scrolling on Wikipedia and reading about a science fiction novel with an interesting premise, but I can for the life of me remember what it was called. Thankfully, I do remember certain characteristics that it had.

It was an older pulp-style story, and the synopsis is that this guy is hunting down and killing these different villains one by one out of revenge for them attacking his planet.

Another detail I remember is that each novel in this series focused on a different villain, and there were either five or six of them in total. While the main bad guy of the first book was an alien, the rest of them were human.

Answer (score 20):

**[Demon Princes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40885.The_Demon_Princes) by Jack Vance**

> Demon Princes is a series of five science fiction novels by Jack Vance, which cumulatively relate the story of an adventurer, Kirth Gersen, as he exacts his revenge on five notorious criminals, collectively known as the Demon Princes, who carried the people of his village off into slavery during his childhood. Each novel deals with his pursuit of one of the five Princes, which extends from Earth to other planets using spaceships.
>
> [Demon Princes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Princes)

I haven't read it, but the synopsis seems to match.

The books were published between 1964 and 1981 which puts it firmly in "older pulp style story" territory.

As Invisible Trihedron has pointed out, the villain of the first book is actually an alien imitating a human:

> He has also deduced that Malagate is not, as widely assumed, human, but rather a "Star King", a member of a species that can rapidly evolve in a few generations to resemble its most successful rival. After contacting humans, the Star Kings began changing their appearance to look more and more like Man. The most successful can readily pass for human.
>
> [Star King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_King)

Comment: And yes, the villain in the first book (_Star King_) turns out to be an alien mimicking a human. As to the revenge, as he expresses it himself, Kirth Gersen feels it more as a moral imperative imposed on him by his grandfather than as hate and anger. He is an interesting character.

Comment: The first thing I thought of.  Mind you, it's not Jack Vance's best work. So I wouldn't go out of my way to read it.

Comment: The first book isn't very good. But *The Face* and *The Killing Machine* are wonderful.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Each to his own taste: I've always thought _The Killing Machine_ was the weakest of the five. But I relish Vance's sense of satire. Has there ever been a class reunion like the one in _The Book of Dreams_?

Comment: I agree that the first book isn't all that good - but *The Killing Machine* is great SF adventure. IMO.

Comment: I absolutely **looove** Vance, but the one thing I recall from this series is the protagonist calculating his ship's orbital insertion point using a [slide rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule).  Turned me off to reading Golden Age SF Space Opera, almost on its own.  Tschai Planet of Adventure thankfully avoids too much space travel considerations.  And Cugel and Lyonesse are enchanting series to start Vance with.

Answer (score 5):

Are you thinking of the [*Last Legionary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary) series?  In the first book Keill's homeworld is wiped out, leaving him the titular Last Legionary.  He is recruited by the Overseers to fight against a shadowy evil leader known as "The Warlord" and the organization, the "Deathwing" that he/she/it leads.  Most of the lesser scope villians that Keill fights through the books are mutants of some sort; in the first book the mutant has visible changes in the form of leathery armour plating, the second book the mutant is a telepath but looks normal.

There were [5 books in the series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?6248) published between 1979 and 1982:

[image: Cover of "Galactic Warlord" showing Keill in combat with Thr'un]
[image: Cover of "Deathwing over Veyna" showing Keill fighting the multi-armed mining robot]
[image: Cover of "Day of the Starwind" showing Keill escaping the tower as it collapses]
[image: Cover of "Planet of the Warlord" showing Keill shooting at the Warlord's troops]
[image: Cover of "Young Legionary"]

Comment: I was sure this was obscure enough that I would be the first to answer. But no... (well done)